# How to assess linearity in multiple linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, linear

I have a question about how to check if the relationship between the independent variable, yt , and the explanatory variables t and t^2 is linear?
I fitted the linear regression with the AUTO-REGRESSIVE time series errors. I

Comment: I have edited the title to better reflect the body.

Comment: You mean: linear vs. quadratic? Or: linear vs. nonlinear?

Comment: linear vs. quadratic

Comment: You could compare a goodness-of-fit measure (R^2, BIC) for a linear model vs a quadratic model.

Comment: The p-value associated with the t^2 term should indicate roughly whether or not there is curvature in your data. You can also decompose your data by removing the time series component and then visually assess the remaining signal to see if there is any polynomial terms necessary.